# Odometry using wheel encoder with no differential drive

Tags: mobile-robot, algorithm, odometry, autonomous-car

I am currently looking for a way to do odometry using wheel encoders, for a car that has no differential drive. The two rear wheel would rotate at the exact same speed. I have been looking everywhere for an answer, but unable to find any. I am starting to think that this is not a possible thing to do. I would be very grateful if anybody can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: how does the vehicle turn?

Comment: Do you mean a car with ackermann steering but a locked differential (solid rear axle)?

Answer (score 2):

So long you have a sensor to read the angle of the steering wheel, you can use the [bicycle kinematic model](https://borrelli.me.berkeley.edu/pdfpub/IV_KinematicMPC_jason.pdf) to compute odometry for an [Ackermann drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry) platform, e.g. a car:

$$
\begin{align}
 \\
\dot{x} & = v \; cos(\psi + \beta) \\ \\
\dot{y} & = v \; sin(\psi + \beta) \\ \\
\dot{\psi} & = \frac{v}{l_r} sin(\beta) \\ \\
\beta  & = tan^{-1} \left ( \frac{l_r}{l_f + l_r} tan(\delta_f) \right )
\end{align}
$$

Where $v$ is linear forward velocity, $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ are the linear velocities alongside the Cartesian axes, $\psi$ and $\dot{\psi}$ are the heading angle and angular velocity, $l_f$ and $l_r$ are the distances from the center of mass to the front an rear axles, and $\delta_f$ is the steering wheel angle.

[image]

Assuming $v$ and $\delta_f$ are retrieved using encoders or other sensors, the vehicle pose can be approximated by:

$$
\begin{align}
 \\
x_t & = x_{t - 1} + \dot{x} \; \Delta t \\ \\
y_t & = y_{t - 1} + \dot{y} \; \Delta t \\ \\
\psi_t & = \psi_{t - 1} + \dot{\psi} \; \Delta t \\ \\
\end{align}
$$